# Test localhost:8080 on IOS device

Tags: ios, testing, localhost

I need to test my website running on localhost on IOS device as the customer claims that the problem only appears on mobile ios device (buttons not visible).

I wanted to know what is the best option to test localhost on IOS device? Is there a free simulator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your iPhone and server which hosts the localhost are in same network, if they are in same network you can simply open browser in your iPhone and type in `http://localhost:8080` and that should work, if they arent in same network then you need public IP of the server to connect to it, url will change to `http://server.public.ip.here:8080`, if you have domain name for the public ip then you can use the domain name instead in your url `http://domain_name:8080`

Comment: phpwin or using a python ide and running the simplehttp server depending what kind of language use your web server.